# How can we prove that Job Scheduling Problem with penalties is in NP?

Tags: algorithm

How can we prove that Job Scheduling Problem with penalties is in NP?

Comment: This might be more suitable on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: With penalties for what? Preemption, migration, exceeding deadline (tardiness)?

Comment: yes deadlines only.it has J1..Jn jobs, t1..tn execution time,p1..pn penalties and d1..dn deadlines.

Answer (score 0):

According to [these course notes](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~bai/ECS122A/npnotes2.pdf), reduction from Subset Sum can be used to show that Job Scheduling
with penalties is also NP-complete.

Answer (score 0):

The standard nondeterministic approach ("guess then check") should work here: Guess how the jobs should be scheduled, then check that this schedule comes in under the penalty limit (which is obviously possible in polynomial time).

Usually, showing that a problem is *in* NP is relatively easy -- the harder part is showing that it is also NP-complete (but in this case, you don't seem to need to do that).